# Kotlin - Spinner Fragments Not Populating

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, spinner

I have looked at EVERY thread on here but cant seem to figure out why my Spinner isn't populating.  I have tried all of these setups and cant seem to get my Spinners to populate.  The app runs fine but nothing appears in the dropdowns.

In .kt file

```
//Setting Spinner Info
        val weight_units = resources.getStringArray(R.array.weight_units)
        val nut_spinner = binding.nutSpinner
        val units = arrayOf("One", "Two", "Three")
        if (nut_spinner != null) {

           /*
            val t = inflater.inflate(com.example.cc_tabbed.R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
            val spinner = t.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.nutSpinner) as Spinner
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.weight_units, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
            )/*

            //val nut_adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, weight_units.toList())
            //val nut_adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(requireActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, weight_units)
            //val nut_adapter = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter<String>(it, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, weight_units) }
            //val nut_adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, weight_units)
            //nut_spinner.adapter = nut_adapter
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">CC-Tabbed</string>
    <string name="tab_text_1">Converter</string>
    <string name="tab_text_2">Local Database</string>
    <string-array name="weight_units">
        <item>lb</item>
        <item>oz</item>
        <item>gram</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

The relevant Spinner in the .xml file

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/desSpinner"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
```

Can anyone provide me any direction here?  I am VERY new to programming in general and have sortof just stumbled my way to a working version of my Android App but Im learning as I go and have a hiccup here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To populate data in `Spinner` component via xml you can use the attribute `android:entries` and define an array of strings into the strings.xml file like below:

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spinner"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:entries="@array/spinnerData" />
```

where `@array/spinnerData` is define in your strings.xml like below:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="spinnerData">
        <item>Spinner Item 1</item>
        <item>Spinner Item 2</item>
        <item>Spinner Item 3</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

or Programmatically in Fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
   val spinner = view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
   val spinnerData = arrayOf("Spinner Item 1", "Spinner Item 2", "Spinner Item 3", "Spinner Item 4")
   spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerData)
}
```

**Result:**

[image: spinner_sample]